# PHP calculator results in a new page? PHP first attempt

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the website to send the calculation results to another page. The code below is working but I have no idea how to get the rows with the results to be shown in a new page.

I know that i have to change the action below to /mynewpage

But I just want the results not the whole table.

I have no idea what to do to the code to make it show the results only in a new page. IF everything statys in the same page the calculator works well.

It's my first attempt with PHP, I clearly have no idea of what I'm doing. Many thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];
if (isset($_POST['valuec'])) $valuec = $_POST['valuec'];
if (isset($_POST['valued'])) $valued = $_POST['valued'];
if (isset($_POST['valuee'])) $valuee = $_POST['valuee'];

$balance = $valuec * $valuee;
$newphone = $valuea;
$total = $balance + $valuea;
$total2 = $balance + $valueb;



echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='/'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>CALCULATOR</strong></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Phone Value:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Phone upfront cost:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Monthly contract cost:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuec' value="$valuec"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Contract duration:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valued' value="$valued"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>No. months left in the contract:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuee' value="$valuee"/></td></tr>


<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;
?>


    <tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>OPTION 1 - PAY REMAINING OF THE CONTRACT AND BUY SAME PHONE UNLOCKED</strong></td></tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
    <td><i>Payment left to network:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($balance)?>"></td></i>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
    <td><i>New unlocked phone:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($newphone)?>"></td></i>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
    <td><i>TOTAL:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($total)?>"></td></i>
    </tr>
    <br>
    <tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>OPTION 2 - PAY BALANCE LEFT AND GET SAME PHONE ON A NEW CONTRACT*</strong></td></tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
    <td><i>Payment left to network:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($balance)?>"></td></i>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
    <td><i>New contract phone initial cost:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($valueb)?>"></td></i>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calcrow">
    <td><i>TOTAL:</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($total2)?>"></td></i>
    </tr></table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either send the values in a form and receive them on the other page using

```
$value1 = $_GET['value1'];
$value2 = $_GET['value2']; // etc
```

The other method would be saving them in a session variable, at the top of any pages where you wish to use session variables, call **session_start()**, then save them

```
$_SESSION['value1'] = $value1;
```

Then in another page, you can call them by simply

```
echo $_SESSION['value1'];
```

Comment: Not really, but I didn't specify the method, I simply told him to send them in a form, I don't really have to spoon feed him everything.. I'd suppose that he has the knowledge to know that if he sent a POST request, he'd use $_POST and if he used a GET request, he'd use $_GET or if he simply didn't use any method at all, default would be $_GET, which is what I used.. @MatthewBrown

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to print your answers on a new page but lets keep it simple: A good way to do it would be for you to separate out the HTML form that posts the values and the php calculation logic on two different pages. So for example, your HTML form is in one file values.php (does not have any php code, you can name it with a .html prefix as well) and the php code is in another file calc.php. Now, to your form, specify an action such as

`<form method='post' action='calc.php'>`

This will post all the values to calc.php where your calculation code is and you can display the results however you please (not limited to a form again) but in a table or so on. Once you learn ajax, you'll never want to come back to doing this.

Here is a working barebones example: http://runnable.com/VEKvtTTrkXFwjAwL/calculator555-for-php

Comment: Worked very well. The process looks much better. Huge thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by new page?  If you have a script like process.php that has that code then you can add session_start(); as your first line after the php start tag.  By using $_Session['result']=$calc_result;  on the 'process.php' you will store the value in your session.  In the 'new page' script you call session_start(); again and you can get the stored value by saying $_Session['result'].